# sharepoint 2013 web part generates broken javascript like &apos;function&apos; on home page

Tags: sharepoint-2013

My homepage generate invalid javascript code, so it throws javascript error and other JS functions dont work;
Code is;

```
if(typeof(MSOLayout_MakeInvisibleIfEmpty) == &apos;function&apos;) {
   MSOLayout_MakeInvisibleIfEmpty();
}
```

As you see error is : `&apos;function&apos;`
it must be "function"

how do i fix it?

Comment: Is this a sharepoint issue (as you tagged it), or javascript issue (as you described it)?

Comment: This is a sharepoint issue. Sharepoint automatic generates javascript, we dont. Problem is `&apos;function&apos;` it must be `'function'`

Comment: Sharepoint patch level ? Sharepoint on-premise or 365 ? WebPart App or Visual Web Part (with wsp) ? Your web part or from other source ? Have you tried to develop an empty web part to reproduce the problem ? On EventViewer (if on premise) have any entry ? on ULS Log (if on premise) have any entry ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing your trying to hide empty web part zones and copied and pasted the following code:

```
if(typeof(MSOLayout_MakeInvisibleIfEmpty) == "function") {
    MSOLayout_MakeInvisibleIfEmpty();
}
```

Here are a couple of things to try to fix your issue.

1. Make sure that the pasted code includes the double quotes and not the `&apos;` that might have been carried over when you copied and pasted it. If you see `&apos;` in your code, replace it with actually typing the double quote (").
2. If it shows as double quotes in the master page (or .html file of the master page) try deleting them and retyping them. It is possible they appear as double quotes but are actually being generated through your text editor and still `&apos;` behind the scenes.

Hope this helps!